# maven version upgrade to google-cloud-bigtable causing issues : SecretManagerServiceStubSettings overrides final method

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I wanted to upgrade to the latest version of google-cloud-bigtable from 2.30.0 to 2.36.0. as soon as I upgrade my application start failing. I tried to find the root cause for it and the error says SecretManagerServiceStubSettings is trying to override the final method call Stubsetting.getEndpoint().

```
class com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.stub.SecretManagerServiceStubSettings overrides final method com.google.api.gax.rpc.StubSettings.getEndpoint()Ljava/lang/String;
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:825)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:344)
     org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:149)
     org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:195)
     org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:114)
     org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:77)
     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
     org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
     org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
     java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:369)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:329)
    
    
    
com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.stub.SecretManagerServiceStubSettings overrides final method com.google.api.gax.rpc.StubSettings.getEndpoint()Ljava/lang/String;
     java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
     java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
     java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
     com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceSettings$Builder.createDefault(SecretManagerServiceSettings.java:259)
     com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceSettings$Builder.access$000(SecretManagerServiceSettings.java:239)
     com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceSettings.newBuilder(SecretManagerServiceSettings.java:216)
     com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.secretmanager.SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.createSecretManagerClient(SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.java:115)
     com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.secretmanager.SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.lambda$registerSecretManagerBeans$0(SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.java:75)
     org.springframework.boot.BootstrapRegistry$InstanceSupplier.lambda$from$1(BootstrapRegistry.java:160)
     org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.getInstance(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:119)
     org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.getOrElseThrow(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:111)
     org.springframework.boot.DefaultBootstrapContext.get(DefaultBootstrapContext.java:88)
     com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.secretmanager.SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.createSecretManagerTemplate(SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.java:132)
     com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.secretmanager.SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.registerSecretManagerBeans(SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.java:85)
     com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.secretmanager.SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(SecretManagerConfigDataLocationResolver.java:60)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$resolve$1(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:102)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:113)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:102)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:94)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:106)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:98)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:115)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processWithProfiles(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:313)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:234)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:96)
     org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
     org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:109)
     org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:94)
     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
     org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
     org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
     org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
     java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:369)
     org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:329)
    \t... 18 common frames omitted
```

I couldn't find the trace of getEndpoint() method in SecretManagerServiceStubSettings.

Comment: This means the library owner made some non-binary-compatible changes to their code.  You'll have to completely rebuild your client against the new library.

Comment: what do you mean by rebuild my client against the new library. I have tried updating all the older versioned dependencies and cleanup my m2 folder and then rebuilt all my application. that still couldn't help